# How to select the first value in a row going backward in columns that isnt NA

Tags: r, dplyr, row, mutate

My dataframe is the following:

```
wave <- data.frame(ID=c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
                      income_wave_1_2017=c(109, 106, NA, 10, 65, NA),
                      income_wave_2_2018=c(NA, 108, 66, NA, NA, 190),
                      income_wave_3_2019=c(19, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA))
```

How can I get this:

```
wave <- data.frame(ID=c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
                      newest_income_=c(19, 108, 66, 10, 65, 190))
```

THX

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `rev`ersed `coalesce`:

```r
library(dplyr)
wave %>% 
  mutate(a = do.call(coalesce, rev(across(-ID))), .keep = "unused")

#  ID   a
#1  1  19
#2  2 108
#3  3  66
#4  4  10
#5  5  65
#6  6 190
```

Or, by specifying the columns:

```r
wave %>% 
  mutate(a = coalesce(income_wave_3_2019, income_wave_2_2018, income_wave_1_2017),
         .keep = "unused")
```